# Calling multiple functions on form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am trying to do JavaScript form validation, and to do this I need to call multiple functions. One to validate the email, one for the password (which so far are the only two that seem to be working) and others for the gender, grade, first name, and last name.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
function emailmatch() { 
  var emailone = document.forms['input']['email'].value;
  var emailtwo = document.forms['input']['email1bID'].value;
  var passwordone = document.forms['input']['password'].value;
  var passwordtwo = document.forms['input']['password1bID'].value;

  if ( emailone != emailtwo ) {
    alert ( "Emails do not match!" );
    document.forms['input']['email'].value = '';
    document.forms['input']['email1bID'].value = '';
    return false;
  }

  else if ( passwordone != passwordtwo ) {
    alert ( "Passwords do not match!" );
    document.forms['input']['password'].value = '';
    document.forms['input']['password1bID'].value = '';
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function checkFirstname() {
  var firstname = document.forms['input']['firstname'].value;
  if (firstname == null) { return false; }
  return true;
}

function checkLastname() {
  var lastname = document.forms['input']['lastname'].value;
  if (lastname == null) { return false; }
  return true;
}

function checkGender() {
  var gender = document.forms['input']['gender'].value;
  if (gender == null) { return false; }
  return true;
}

function validateform() {
  var validation = true;
  if ((emailmatch() && checkFirstname() && checkLastname && checkgender()) == true) return validation;
}
```

And then here is the html form:

```
<form name="input" id="input" onSubmit="return validateform()" method="GET" action="code.php">
  <tr><td>First name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""></td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td>Last name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""></td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td>Gender:</td><td> <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td>Grade:</td><td> <input type="radio" name="grade" value="9"> 9 <input type="radio" name="grade" value="10"> 10 <input type="radio" name="grade" value="11"> 11 <input type="radio" name="grade" value="12"> 12<br /> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Email:</td><td> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""></td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td>Verify Email:</td><td> <input type="text" name="email1b" id="email1bID" value=""></td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td>Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""></td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td>Verify Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password1b" id="password1bID" value=""></td></tr> <br />
  <tr><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center></td></tr>
</form>
```

So overall I've created all the functions and even created a function to call them all on submit, though the only ones that are actually working are the email and the password. It calls to a code that inputs it to the database (which is also working), so that isn't the issue. Where are the validation codes going wrong?

Comment: You haven't said what the error is that you're experiencing. Please give more details about what is not working.

Comment: This looks like a simple task that can be debugged using firebug

Comment: Don't compare the values to `null`. Compare to `""`

Answer (score 0):

Because you never return false!

```
    function validateform()
    {   var validation = true;  <-- set to true
        if ((emailmatch() && checkFirstname() && checkLastname && checkgender())== true)
    return validation;  <--- returns true
    <-- if false you do not return anything
   }
```

Either add a return false, or change it to a return with all the checks.

```
   function validateform () {   
       return emailmatch() && checkFirstname() && checkLastname && checkgender();
   }
```

After you get that straight, you have to realize that an empty string is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event click on the button `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateform();"/>`

And submit the form via javascript.

```
function validateform()
{
    var validation = true;
    if( (emailmatch() && checkFirstname() && checkLastname && checkGender())== true)
    document.forms['input'].submit();
}

<form name="input" id="input" method="GET" action="code.php">
<tr><td>First name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""></td></tr> <br />
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""></td></tr> <br />
<tr><td>Gender:</td><td> <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</td></tr> <br />
<tr><td>Grade:</td><td> <input type="radio" name="grade" value="9"> 9 <input type="radio" name="grade" value="10"> 10 <input type="radio" name="grade" value="11"> 11 <input type="radio" name="grade" value="12"> 12<br /> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""></td></tr> <br />
<tr><td>Verify Email:</td><td> <input type="text" name="email1b" id="email1bID" value=""></td></tr> <br />
<tr><td>Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""></td></tr> <br />
<tr><td>Verify Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password1b" id="password1bID" value=""></td></tr> <br />
```

also look at your function: checkGender(), in the if statement you call checkgender()